# Manipulating SVG via JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG tag similar to the one below

```
<svg width="696" height="582" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart."><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_4"><clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5"><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="360"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="696" height="582" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="360" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g clip-path="url(...#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5)"><g><rect x="70" y="470" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="398" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="326" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="255" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="183" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="434" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="362" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="291" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="219" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="147" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect></g><g><rect x="70" y="470" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333"></rect></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="475.4" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="403.59999999999997" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.2</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="331.79999999999995" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.4</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="260" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.6</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="188.20000000000002" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.8</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="116.4" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">1.0</text></g></g></g><g></g></svg>
```

​

Is there a way, via JS to remove the `<g clip-path="url(...#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5)">`?

Comment: Yes. The DOM works on SVG too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove it when you can select it. Did you try

```
let svg_gTag = document.querySelector('svg g[clip-path="url(...#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5)"]');
svg_gTag.parentNode.removeChild(svg_gTag);
```

I tried to scribble that:

```js
let svg_gTag = document.querySelector('svg#demo g[clip-path="url(...#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5)"]');
svg_gTag.parentNode.removeChild(svg_gTag);
```

```html
<svg id="demo" width="696" height="582" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart."><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_4"><clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5"><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="360"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="696" height="582" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="360" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g clip-path="url(...#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_5)"><g><rect x="70" y="470" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="398" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="326" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="255" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="183" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="111" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="70" y="434" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="362" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="291" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="219" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect><rect x="70" y="147" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ebebeb"></rect></g><g><rect x="70" y="470" width="557" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#333333"></rect></g></g><g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="475.4" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="403.59999999999997" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.2</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="331.79999999999995" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.4</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="260" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.6</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="188.20000000000002" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0.8</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="56" y="116.4" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">1.0</text></g></g></g><g></g></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, the main problem I have using `querySelector` is that the url changes every time.

Comment: Is there anything you can be sure of? N-th child? Only g with attribute clip-path, part of the url or something else? querySelector accepts regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up to remove the `clip-path` attribute completely. `svg_gTag.removeAttribute('clip-path')`